# Bluetooth sharing mechanism on Android

Tags: bluetooth, share-menu, file-sharing, screen-sharing, shareit

I am using a Realme 8 5G Android 12 phone.

How do I share a contact with other users nearby (on their mobile phones), via the Bluetooth mechanism of the icon on the upper left in the picture below?

What is this mechanism called, and, how does it work?

[image: notification drawer with Bluetooth sharing icon]

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but what is from your perspective in the upper left part of the screenshot? To me the upper left part starts with an empty section and then comes the clock...

Comment: Did you mean by using [Nearby Share](https://support.google.com/files/answer/10514188)?

Comment: Yes, it was helpful to know that that feature was the peer-to-peer (P2P), nearby share. Thank you for the link (this could be useful for sharing apps and files in places with no network coverage). Thanks.